# dopar glmnet failing silently

Tags: r, parallel-processing, glmnet, domc

I'm using `glmnet` to fit some models and am cross-validating for `lambda`. I'm using `cv.glmnet` by default (since it does complete cross-validation 
 of `lambda` internally), but below I focus on the first step of that function, which is the one causing issues.

First data setup. I haven't made a reproducible example and can't share the raw data, but `dim(smat)` is roughly 4.7M rows by 50 columns, about half of which are dense. I tried a simplistic approach to reproducing the issue with completely random columns, to no avail.

```
# data setup (censored)
library(data.table)
DT = fread(...)
n_cv = 10L

# assign cross-validation group to an ID (instead of to a row)
IDs = DT[ , .(rand_id = runif(1L)), keyby = ID]
IDs[order(rand_id), cv_grp := .I %% n_cv + 1L]
DT[IDs, cv_grp := i.cv_grp, on = 'ID']

# key by cv_grp to facilitate subsetting different training sets
setkey(DT, cv_grp)
# assign row number as column to facilitate subsetting model matrix
DT[ , rowN := .I]

library(glmnet)
library(Matrix)

# y is 0/1 (actually TRUE/FALSE)
model = y ~ ...
smat = sparse.model.matrix(model, data = DT)
# this is what's done internally to 0-1 data to create
#   an n x 2 matrix with FALSE in the 1st and TRUE in the 2nd column
ymat = diag(2L)[factor(DT$y), ]
```

The following is a tailored version of what `cv.glmnet` does before passing to `cv.lognet`:

```
train_models = lapply(seq_len(n_cv), function(i) {
  train_idx = DT[!.(i), rowN]
  glmnet(smat[train_idx, , drop = FALSE], ymat[train_idx, ],
         alpha = 1, family = 'binomial')
})
```

This appears to work fine, but is quite slow. If we replace this by the equivalent version for `parallel = TRUE`:

```
library(doMC)
registerDoMC(detectCores())
train_models_par = foreach(i = seq_len(n_cv), .packages = c("glmnet", "data.table")) %dopar% {
  train_idx = DT[!.(i), rowN]
  glmnet(smat[train_idx, , drop = FALSE], ymat[train_idx, ],
         alpha = 1, family = 'binomial')
}
```

The `glmnet` call fails silently on some nodes (compared to `any(sapply(train_models, is.null))` which is `FALSE`):

```
sapply(train_models_par, is.null)
# [1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Which task fails is inconsistent (so it's not a problem with, e.g., `cv_grp = 2` *per se*). I've tried capturing the output of `glmnet` and checking `is.null` to no avail. I've also added the `.verbose = TRUE` flag to `foreach` and nothing suspicious emerges. Note that the `data.table` syntax is ancillary, as the default behavior of `cv.glmnet` (which also results in similar failures) relies on using `which = foldid == i` to split training and test sets.

How can I debug this problem? Why might the task fail when parallelized, but not serially, and how can I catch when the task has failed (so that I can try-and-retry, for example)?

Current info about environment:

```
sessionInfo()
# R version 3.4.3 (2017-11-30)
# Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
# Running under: Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
# 
# Matrix products: default
# BLAS: /usr/lib/libblas/libblas.so.3.6.0
# LAPACK: /usr/lib/lapack/liblapack.so.3.6.0
# 
# locale:
#  [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8      
#  [2] LC_NUMERIC=C              
#  [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8       
#  [4] LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
#  [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8   
#  [6] LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
#  [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8      
#  [8] LC_NAME=C                 
#  [9] LC_ADDRESS=C              
# [10] LC_TELEPHONE=C            
# [11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8
# [12] LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       
# 
# attached base packages:
# [1] parallel  stats     graphics  grDevices utils    
# [6] datasets  methods   base     
# 
# other attached packages:
# [1] ggplot2_2.2.1     doMC_1.3.5       
# [3] iterators_1.0.8   glmnet_2.0-13    
# [5] foreach_1.4.3     Matrix_1.2-12    
# [7] data.table_1.10.5
# 
# loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
#  [1] Rcpp_0.12.14     lattice_0.20-35 
#  [3] codetools_0.2-15 plyr_1.8.3      
#  [5] grid_3.4.3       gtable_0.1.2    
#  [7] scales_0.5.0     rlang_0.1.4     
#  [9] lazyeval_0.2.1   tools_3.4.3     
# [11] munsell_0.4.2    yaml_2.1.13     
# [13] compiler_3.4.3   colorspace_1.2-4
# [15] tibble_1.3.4   

system('free -m')
# total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
# Mem:          30147        1786       25087           1        3273       28059
# Swap:             0           0           0

detectCores()
# [1] 16

system('lscpu | grep "Model name"')
# Model name:            Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2666 v3 @ 2.90GHz
```

Comment: what is your rsession info and system specs? Otherwise maybe just use `try`/`purrr::safely` to see if you can return an error that way?

Comment: @zacdav added a bunch of info about my instance. Could you elaborate / point to some example of using `purrr`? As noted, it's not an _error_ that's emerging, and simply trying to catch the output with `is.null` doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: did you found any solution for this @MichaelChirico?

Comment: @abhiieor I'm afraid not sorry